# LiquidSoap - random not working as expected

Tags: icecast, liquidsoap

From my liquidsoap configuration:

```
radio = random(weights = [1, 4], [jingles,standard])
```

I interpret this as playing 1 random jingle for every 4 random tracks from the 'standard' playlist.

But I often get 2 jingles playing consecutively.  Am I misunderstanding the logic of the configuration?  How can I make it just play ONE jingle only for each 4 standard playlist tracks?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this config:

```
jingles = once(jingles)
```

Put it before your random point.
Let me know if this helps.